Expand the multivariable function into a Maclaurin series

Expand the multivariable function into a Maclaurin series including terms up to the sixth order $$f(x,y)=\sqrt[5]{cos(x^2+y^3)}$$

I've been trying to calculate the partial derivatives, but they are all huge and scary, and when I substitute $(0,0)$, it turns out that these derivatives are also zero (at least up to the second order). The function's value at the point $(0,0)$ is $1$. Therefore, I'm completely confused about how to approach this task and what I'm doing wrong. Moreover, I don't understand how to compute up to the sixth order with such complicated expressions for the derivatives.

Are you sure it's $y^3$ and not $y^2$? It will get complicated to track so many terms

As $x^2+y^3\to0 $ when $x\to 0, y\to 0$, we may find the Taylor Series of $g(t)=\sqrt[5]{\cos(t)}$ at $t=0$ and then plug in $t=x^2+y^3$.
Notice that $$g(0)=1\\g'(t)=-\dfrac{\sin(t)}{5\cos^{4/5}(t)}\implies g'(0)=0\\g''(t)=\dfrac{-5\cos^{9/5}(t)-4\sin^2(t)\cos^{-1/5}(t)}{25\cos^{8/5}(t)}\implies g''(0)=-\dfrac{1}{5}\\g'''(t)=\dfrac{-35 \cos^2(t) \sin(t) - 36 \sin^3(t)}{125 \cos^{14/5}(t)}\implies g'''(0)=0$$
(Instead of computing the third derivative, we could have noticed that $g$ is an even function so all its odd derivatives at $0$ are $0$).
Consequently, we may write $g(t)=1-\dfrac{t^2}{10}+O(t^4)$. Notice that if $t=x^2+y^3$ then $t^4$ gives us terms with order of at least $8$.
Thus, the Taylor Polynomial of degree $6$ for $f$ is $$P_6f(x,y)=1-\dfrac{(x^2+y^3)^2}{10}=1-\dfrac{x^2y^3}{5}-\dfrac{x^4}{10}-\dfrac{y^6}{10}$$
